How to prepopulate a textfield in Swift with @State and @Bindings
I have a view that gets created and has binding variables passed down to it, but I need to pre-populate a textfield using a value from one of these bindings. It should update with onAppear but it does not. For context the logic goes like this: user inputs a 2 digit pin, which gets converted to a base64 encoded value for a channel psk. And when this view loads, I need to take this base64 key and do the reverse and show the simple 2 digit pin, using NSData conversion and unwrapping. And the pin can be editted and changed to another key value.
Parent view
.sheet(item: $selectedChannel) { selection in
    editChannelView(channelIndex: $channelIndex, channelName: $channelName, channelKeySize: $channelKeySize, channelKey: $channelKey, channelRole: $channelRole, uplink: $uplink, downlink: $downlink, hasChanges: $hasChanges, hasValidKey: $hasValidKey)
}


editChannelView
func unwrap<T>(_ any: T) -> Any {
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: any)
    guard mirror.displayStyle == .optional, let first =
            mirror.children.first else {
        return any
    }
    return unwrap(first.value)
}

struct ChannelForm: View {
    @Binding var channelIndex: Int32
    @Binding var channelName: String
    @Binding var channelKeySize: Int
    @Binding var channelKey: String
    @Binding var channelRole: Int
    @Binding var uplink: Bool
    @Binding var downlink: Bool
    @Binding var hasChanges: Bool
    @Binding var hasValidKey: Bool
    
    @State private var encodedKey = "N/A"
    @State private var channelKeyAsNum = "0" //here
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                TextField("Key", text: $channelKeyAsNum)
            }
            .onChange(of: channelKeyAsNum, perform: { value in
                //convert 2 digit pin to base64 key
                var base64EncodedString = ""
                if let intValue = UInt8(channelKeyAsNum) {
                    var data = Data([intValue])
                    base64EncodedString = data.base64EncodedString() }
                
                let tempKey = Data(base64Encoded: base64EncodedString) ?? Data()
                
                if tempKey.count == channelKeySize {
                    channelKey = base64EncodedString
                    hasValidKey = true
                }
            })
            .onAppear(perform: {
                let base64EncodedData = Data(base64Encoded: channelKey, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)
                let array2 = base64EncodedData?.bytes
                channelKeyAsNum = unwrap(array2?[0]) as! String. // doesn't update textfield
            })
        }
    }
}


what does unwrap(array2?[0]) as! String return ?

your on change will execute 2 times on initial, and you can check the value of channelKeyAsNum each time, and see if that behaves as expected.
